# gnucash - Record several years data

Tags: gnucash, bookkeeping

Currently I am using GnuCash to record my personal expenses.
I am using it since the last year, so in my master book I have records belonging to the years 2013 and 2014.
Is that the correct way to record them? Should I split every year in a new book, or it's ok to put everything inside the a single one?
Please remember that I am recording personal expenses, so there aren't so many records.

Finally, what's the best way to have a report of the expenses breakdown?
I mean: *in 2013 you spent XXX for clothes, in 2014 you spent YYY*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should keep doing it the way it is most comfortable for you, but I'd suggest not splitting.

GnuCash is perfectly capable of generating reports for any given time range, and it is much easier and straightforward to keep one book. That's how accounting in general works (for a business, keeping multiple books is in fact a crime).

You break down your expenses using *accounts*, and then you can produce yearly (or any other time period) reports of your income and expenses.